# Не работает оператор INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

Не получается вставить данные в виде новой строки в phpmyadmin.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'thismovie');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Соединение не установлено", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

/*$query = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM movie');

while ( $row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    echo $row['Name'].$row['Year']."<br>";
}*/

$query = "INSERT INTO movie VALUES(null, 'Безумный Макс', 'Описание фильма Безумный Макс', '2015', Now())";
$mysqli->query($query);

$mysqli->close();
```

?>

Comment: Вам рекомендуется указать название полей в таблице. `"INSERT INTO movie (id,поле1,поле2,поле3,поле4) VALUES(null, 'Безумный Макс', 'Описание фильма Безумный Макс', '2015', Now())";` Где поле_номер - это толбцы в Вашей таблице.

Comment: @Denis640Kb необходимо неправильный термин. правильнее будет "рекомендуется, чтобы избежать проблем в будущем при изменении структуры таблицы"

Comment: Все также ничего не происходит